Google Ad Sense doesn't remove the slots sometimes even with the given class the provide
So I'm using Google Ads with Next.js, and this is how I have installed it:
const _document: FC = (): ReactNode => {
    return (
        <Html>
            <Head />

            <body>
                <Script
                    async
                    src={`https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=${ADS_CLIENT}`}
                    crossOrigin='anonymous'
                    strategy='afterInteractive'
                />

                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
    )
}

export default _document

And this is the ad unit component where, for each ad, I load it using useEffect.
const Ad: FC<AdComponentPropTypes> = (props): ReactNode => {
    const { 
        slot, 
        className, 
        responsive
    } = props

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
                (adsbygoogle = (window as any).adsbygoogle || []).push({})
            }
        } 
        
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }, [])

    return  (
        <ins 
            style={IS_PRODUCTION ? {} : { background: '#99999925' }}
            data-ad-client={ADS_CLIENT}
            data-ad-slot={slot}
            className={`adsbygoogle flex items-center justify-center ${className}`}
            data-ad-format='auto'
            data-full-width-responsive={responsive ? 'true' : 'false'}
        />
    )
}

export default Ad

And this works fine; it shows ads sometimes and sometimes it doesn't, but this is because of Google Ads, and that is fine. The problem is with a dynamic list. I iterate and inject ads when displaying the list, which is fine, but sometimes it doesn't hide the empty slot, and sometimes it does. This is very weird behavior, and I need someone who might have experienced the same issue to answer.
Here is the list iteration where, based on an algorithm, I sometimes display an ad in a slot, and most of the other content is my gallery images. Here is the code:
const PicsList: FC<PicsListProps> = (): ReactNode => {
    const { gridItems, picSize } = useWidth()
    const { Tab } = ProfileState()
    const { Pics, Loading, HasMore } = PicsState()
    const { PicsGrid } = PicsGridBuilder(Pics === null ? [...MockupPics(picSize || 480, gridItems)] : !Loading || !HasMore ? [...Pics] : [...Pics, ...MockupPics(picSize || 480, gridItems)], gridItems)
    
    return (
        <section className="mx-auto h-full max-w-10xl grid gap-2 md:gap-4 grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-5 2xl:grid-cols-5 3xl:grid-cols-6 4xl:grid-cols-7">
            {Pics !== null && PicsGrid?.map((set_of_pics: any, listIndex: number) => {
                return (
                    <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 md:gap-4" key={listIndex}>
                        {set_of_pics?.map((pic: PicInterface | PicSkeletonTypes, index: number) => {
                            // @ts-ignore
                            if (pic.type === 'ad') return (
                                <Fragment key={Math.random() + index + listIndex}>
                                    <Ad 
                                        className='border-[#D0C3E750] border-4 bg-[var(--skeleton-background)] rounded-[24px] md:rounded-[44px] min-h-[340px] max-h-[340] sm:min-h-[500px] sm:max-h-[500px] overflow-hidden'
                                        slot={AD_UNITS.PIC_ITEM}
                                        responsive={false}
                                    />
                                </Fragment>
                            )

                            else if ('height' in pic) {
                                if (Loading || Pics?.length === 0 || 'height' in PicsGrid[0][0]) return (
                                    <Fragment key={Math.random() + index + listIndex}>
                                        <PicSkeleton height={pic.height} />
                                    </Fragment>
                                )
                            }
                            
                            else return (
                                <Fragment key={pic?._id  + index + listIndex + pic.Title}>
                                    <PicItem admin={Tab === USER_PROFILE_TABS.APPROVAL} {...pic} />
                                </Fragment>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                )
            })}

            {(Pics === null || Loading) && PicsGrid?.map((set_of_pics: any, listIndex: number) => {
                return (
                    <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 md:gap-4" key={listIndex}>
                        {set_of_pics?.map((pic: PicSkeletonTypes, index: number) => {
                            return (
                                <Fragment key={Math.random() + index + listIndex}>
                                    <PicSkeleton height={pic.height} />
                                </Fragment>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </section>
    )
}

export default PicsList

I tried with the classes Google provides but something seems to mis on the puzzle. Here is the anwser from Google: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10762946?hl=en
